# How exactly do we implement swagger docs for django APIView

Tags: django, swagger

So I have a django GenericAPIView Endpoint, for which I want to add swagger documentation. 
I have searched all over the documentation on how to do the django-rest-swagger, but I can't seem to understand them very much. Below are my files.

**views.py**

```
class SignUpAPIView(GenericAPIView):

    """

    get: Not Available

    post: This endpoint presents Sign Up facility for the user.

    Try it urself by sending a request in the below form


    """
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = SignupSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("Only POST Method is allowed")

    def post(self,request,format=None):
        serializer = SignupSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = request.data
        if serializer.is_valid():
            valid_data=serializer.data
            print(valid_data)
        return Response("Success", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class SignupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    mobileNumber = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=10)
    email = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
```

This is the current Swagger Doc UI, that is being rendered.

[image]

How do I make the example value in the Description to something of the below form?

```
{
    "user":{
        "name":"string",
        "username":"string",
        "mobileNumber":"string",
        "email":"string",
        "password":"string"
    }
}
```

Also, If someone could explain how exactly we can create good documentation using swagger, it would be of great help. A brief explanation of how exactly swagger works would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SignupSerializerSub(serializers.Serializer):

    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    mobileNumber = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=10)
    email = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=150)

class SignupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = serializers.ListField(child=SignupSerializerSub())
```

Comment: To add value to your answer consider adding an explanation to what this code does and how it answers the question.